# How can I deal with daedra?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

What enchantments can banish daedra and what level do you have to be?
I have the same question about the which spells can deal with them
and where can I find/buy said enchantment/spell(s)?

Comment: I'm pretty sure [Banish](http://elderscrolls.wikia.com/wiki/Banish_(Effect)) does exactly what you're asking...

Comment: Banish should work, ans its usually an end game spell

Comment: Hi, and welcome on Arqade. If you want to learn how things work here, I suggest you read the [tour](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/tour). An important thing to keep in mind is you should only ask one question at a time ;)

Answer (score 5):

There are two spells which can banish summoned Daedra.

Banish Daedra is the weaker and easier to cast of the two. It is an Adept level Conjuration, requiring 50 skill to cast effectively. It is limited to lower level summons. Expel Daedra is the stronger version. It is an Expert level spell, which requires 75 magicka to cast for a reasonable cost.

Both these spells can be acquired from Phinis Gestor if the Dragonborn has 40 & 70 Conjuration, respectively.

The Oblivion Binding perk may also help here- it causes your weapons to banish any summoned creatures that it hits.

That said, I still prefer Destruction magic, combined with big weapons. An ounce of prevention is worth a pound of cure as they say- in this case your ounce of prevention is killing the summoner.

Comment: Banish is also a valid enchantment. Merchants start selling items with this enchantment when the PC reaches level 22.